# Google Text to Speech always display 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, audio, text-to-speech, moodle

I am developing website using moodle. I need to use Text to Speech so I use Google TTS, also SimpleSpeak is not working on moodle 2.7.

So in my page i have something like this:

```
<audio id="live" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&amp;q=live"      
rel="noreferrer”>
</audio>
<div> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('live').play()" &gt;play=""> 
live
</button> 
</div>
```

But everytime i click the button its not working and when i inspect the code, it gives
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I already add rel="noreferrer".

Can anybody help me to solve this. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed your mistake. In your code you have:

```
rel="noreferrer”
```

instead of

```
rel="noreferrer"
```

You have accidentally mistyped quotation marks.

```
 ” =/= "
```